# Linha de coluna do Datatable com mais de um atributo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Tenho um Datatable com várias colunas. Uma delas é uma coluna que deve ser exibido mais de um atributo em cada linha dessa coluna, pois ele faz parte de um relacionamento ManyToMany. Essa coluna vai receber os atributos de uma Lista. Quero saber como faço para exibir mais de um atributo nas linhas dessa coluna

O datatable com a coluna

```
<p:dataTable id="monografiasDataTable" widgetVar="monografiaTable"
                value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaMonografias}" var="monografia"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma informação a ser exibida" paginator="true"
                rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.monografia}"
                rowKey="#{monografia.id}" >

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="frm:toolbar" />

                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="frm:toolbar" />

            <p:column filterBy="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" headerText="Linha de Pesquisa">
                <f:facet name="filter" >
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu  value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaMonografiasFiltradas}" label="Selecione" onchange="PF('monografiaTable').filter()"
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"> 
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaLinhaPesquisas}"
                            var="listaLinhaPesquisas"
                            itemLabel="#{listaLinhaPesquisas.nome}"
                            itemValue="#{listaLinhaPesquisas}"/>
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" />

            </p:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coluna de um datatable vai mostrar tantas coisas quantas forem colocadas em sua declaração. Supondo que você queira usar um segundo índice do array mostrado faria o seguinte:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" headerText="Linha de Pesquisa">
    <f:facet name="filter" >
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu  value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaMonografiasFiltradas}" label="Selecione" onchange="PF('monografiaTable').filter()"
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"> 
               <f:selectItems
                            value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaLinhaPesquisas}"
                            var="listaLinhaPesquisas"
                            itemLabel="#{listaLinhaPesquisas.nome}"
                            itemValue="#{listaLinhaPesquisas}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" /> 
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[1].nome}" />    
</p:column>
```

Adicionei esse trecho aqui:

```
<br/>
<h:outputText value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[1].nome}" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas como eu deixo para mostrar dinamicamente, pois essa coluna pode receber tanto um atributo como vários

Comment: Nesse caso você pode fazer o seguinte:
1 - Construir uma String que tenha todos os nomes que quer mostrar quando estiver em modo de leitura
2 - Usar algo como um SelectManyMenu com os itens já selecionados quando estiver em modo de edição.

Comment: Você fez eu abrir a cabeça pra outra coisa que tinha pesquisado e não tinha conseguido aplicar, que foi o Datalist. Usei o Datalist e resolvi meu problema, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @DanielAzevedo bom que resolveu. Se a resposta ajudou pode aceitá-la, isso ajuda quem responde :)

Answer (score 0):

A dúvida era boba, mas vou deixar aqui oque resolveu meu problema que pode ajudar outras pessoas.
Usei o Datalist e resolveu meu problema

```
<p:dataList value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas}" var="linhaPesquisa">
                    <h:outputText value="#{linhaPesquisa.nome}" />
                </p:dataList>
```